# How can i overload Index in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've Index page which is included Blogs from database. Firstly, if i dont give the categoryID then all blogs must come to index page. If i give the category then i want to display blogs by categoryID so i need use Index overload.

```
public ActionResult Index(){List<Blog> blogs = db.Blogs.ToList();}
public ActionResult Index(int ID){List<Blog> blogs = db.Blogs.Where(x=>x.CategoryID==ID).ToList();}
```

But when i want to display all blogs the error come like this:

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type SosyalSozluk.Areas.Blog.Controllers.HomeController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32) on type SosyalSozluk.Areas.Blog.Controllers.HomeController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the first method and change the 2nd method to make the parameter optional

```
public ActionResult Index(int? ID)
{
    IEnumerable<Blog> blogs = db.Blogs;
    if (ID.HasValue)
    {
        blogs = blogs .Where(x=>x.CategoryID == ID.Value);
    }
    return View(model); // add `.ToList()` if you really need it
}
```